# Get stream without Page's posts

Tags: facebook-fql

I want to get all the posts in my stream, without the posts that come from pages. I have tried:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, comment_info, likes FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed') AND NOT (actor_id IN (SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE type='Page'))
```

However, you can't use type='Page' in the Where clause because it isn't indexable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look and the following seems to work for me :

```
    SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, comment_info, likes FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed') AND NOT (actor_id IN (SELECT target_id FROM connection WHERE target_type='Page' AND source_id = me()))
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: I don't think it was a stupid mistake,the FQL tables don't match up 1-1 with the graph endpoints otherwise it would be easier to work out!